# How to fix this script to change the value from true to false

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, tampering

This is my first question on your forum, and I wish to find an answer, maybe it's a dumb question for everyone of you but I'm beginning with a JavaScript boot-camp and I'm curious how to do change the highlighted value with TamperMonkey

[image]

Another little question: Is there any macro recorder for TamperMonkey, like the one provided in Microsoft Office products to record a VB macro then edit it later?

**HTML**

```html
<html class=" video videoautoplay">
    <body data-no-turbolink="true">
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" 
    name="viewport">
    <meta id="fedora-keys" data-commit 
    sha="f232f03c4db92d93cff3bee17185864b56d67336" data-env="production"
```

**TamperMonkey Script**

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
   var link = document.createElement('meta');
   link.setAttribute('name', 'data-env');
   link.content = "development";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
})();
```

I'm trying to change "production" to "development" with TamperMonkey, but I blame my ignorance of the programming language.

Regards

Comment: Put the HTML in the question, not a remote image.

Comment: `<meta>` tags should be in the `<head>` element, not the `<body>`

Comment: I've added the HTML code, sorry!

Comment: Welcome George, congrats on your first question! I use TamperMonkey myself, usually to make it easier to interact with `GitHub`. You can find some script examples [here](https://gist.github.com/dougbacelar/2c26e39b1595004951f3251c5d8b5b30)

Comment: @Doug Thank you! I appreciate your help, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to change the element directly:

```
(function() {
   'use strict';
   //get the meta element with id fedora-keys
   var link = document.querySelector('meta#fedora-keys'); 
   //set the data-env attribute to development
   link.setAttribute('data-env', 'development');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('fedora-keys')
        .setAttribute('data-env', 'development')
```

> Is there any macro recorder for TamperMonkey, like the one provided in Microsoft Office products to record a VB macro then edit it later?

I don't think [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net) supports that:

> provides features like a clear overview over the running scripts, a built-in editor, ZIP-based import and export, automatic update checks and browser and cloud storage based synchronization.

Comment: Thank you for the details! appreciate your help and will upvote your reply as  soon as I have the ability to do that